# AWS Elastic BeanStalk Error writing to |/usr/sbin/rotatelogs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an AWS beanstalk app that after a reboot runs pretty smoothly for few hours, then all of the sudden the latency starts creeping up.

[image]

When I check the logs, I find a lot of these messages

[log_config:warn] [pid 15905] (32)Broken pipe: [client 172.31.5.163:31780] AH00646: Error writing to |/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /var/log/httpd/healthd/application.log.%Y-%m-%d-%H 3600

I also read https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/mysql-and-lamp-issue-warning-mysqli_real_connect-hy000-2002

It says if the logs get bigger than 10mb, server could get slow. Not sure if this applies to my case?
I could nt figure out how to fix this and unfortunately I am not an aws pro. Any assistance/ guidance on how to solve this issue would be great!

Comment: I doubt log size is the problem, I would be amazed if your logs get larger than 10mb in just a few hours. Also, I see this error periodically in our logs, and it's not related/correlated to any latency. I would look more closely at things like memory usage, number of simultaneous connections, etc.

Comment: @KayakinKoder ok. Connections can be a cause, but what I dont understand is once it goes up, it never goes back to the low state. The fact that it runs low latency for 1-2 hours means it has seen the average load by then. To me, it means if there is a connection spike, it should come back to the low latency afterwards.   It would have made sense if latency kept rising from the point of reboot, to a point where it stays same. Also the change is abrupt, settles at that higher level and does not keep rising.

Comment: Yes, I would also look at other server metrics: is the RAM usage high? What you need to do as a first step is identify the root cause of the problem. We still don't know if the problem is the hardware, the web server (Apache/Nginx), the database, or possibly even the application code itself. The server hardware itself could be doing fine, but something with Apache is going wrong. Or it could be that your database is getting overwhelmed, or your app code. If you pay for AWS support, I would ask them to take a look, they have by far the best customer service of any SaaS I've ever used.

Comment: @KayakinKoder Yup I see teh point. Unfortunately i dont have paid aws support. :( I will keep digging to see if I can figure out some hints.